# STM32G030 BOOT0 pin - SWCLK

Tags: capacitor, stm32, noise, oscilloscope, swd

I designed a board with an STM32G030C8T6 MCU and some peripherals. The board is working just fine, regarding the functionalities, but I have some issues with flashing.

So, the first "strange" thing to me was that the BOOT0 pin is the same as the SWCLK pin. Generally, I always pull the BOOT0 pin low through a 10k resistor and connect the SWCLK through a 22ohm resistor in series. Here, I was a bit confused. The reference manual states that the BOOT0 pin should be low in order to boot from the main flash memory, which is what I want. So, in the end what seemed to make sense to me was that I connected the SWCLK through a 22ohm resistor to the BOOT0 pin, and I also pulled it low through a 10k resistor.

[image]
[image]

And then, the strangest thing happened... Yesterday, I could program the board from STM32CubeIDE with an ST-Link V3 mini. I had some issues, but in the majority of the cases, it worked, so I did not really pay attention to the programming fails. But today, I had many-many error messages, like "ST-Link device not responding" and "waiting for response", "check the power connection", "GDB server error" and such.

Then I thought, since this BOOT0 vs SWCLK was the only strange thing about the design, I turned on the oscilloscope and measured that pin. I took the GND of the ST-Link as reference and measured the pin right at the MCU... And the programming was successful. Then I played around with it for a while, and the conclusion is the following: the programming was only successful if I measured the pin with the oscilloscope, it was always OK when I measured it and it was never OK when I did not measure it... (yesterday was also sometimes OK when I wasn't measuring, but not today... magic)

So there it is... I don't really know where to put this information... Does anyone have any explanation?

Also, is the 22ohm - 10k solution wrong? What would be the good solution in this case when the two pins are the same? A jumper maybe, so that it is only pulled down through the 10k when I am done programming?

Also, this was what I measured, not the best image, 1.00V / 100ns. This seems a bit noisy to me, but this was the first time I measured the SWCLK or any SW programming pins, so I don't really have a reference. For the NRST, I usually have a 100nF capacitor to avoid parasitic resets. Should I maybe also have a 100nF capacitor for the SWCLK and one for the SWDIO pins as well to reduce noise?

[image]

My only guess is that in fact the problem was that the signal on the SWCLK pin was too noisy, and that is why the programming failed. And when I measured the signal on the pin referenced to the GDN, the input capacitance of the oscilloscope probe acted as a bypass capacitor and reduced the noise so that the programming worked. But as far as I know, an oscilloscope probe should have around 10-25pF, so then a 100nF capacitance would be too much.

Comment: It should work with just the scope ground connected too. If so, that will tell you have a CMRR problem with your signal integrity on your TBD cable.  You ought to consider STP cable with shield terminated at one end only to PE gnd..  You can also improve signal quality changing 22R to 100R to match 22 ohm source to 120 cable and keep probe gnd lead very short. Then use the STP shield gnd connected to PE gnd like the scope.  If that works , I'll write up the answer

Comment: Thank you, you were right about the signal integrity, I reworked the cables from the ST-Link V3 mini to the board (soldered shorter ones). Now, everything is working fine.

Comment: yer most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas for you to try.

Check signal on ST-LINK SWCLK pin with no MCU attached. If there is something on it try powering up MCU before you power up ST-LINK. From 6.3.1 in datasheet: "PA14 is shared with BOOT0 functionality. Caution is required as the debugging device can
manipulate BOOT0 pin value."

Replace R19 with a jumper. See [Typical SWD circuit](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101761/0100/Debug-and-trace-interface/Typical-SWD-circuit) at ARM developer site.

It is not clear if you have NRST pin available on SWD connector. It is not technically required, but *very* helpful in situations like this. If you do have it try configuring ST-LINK for hardware reset. See [this post](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001CoHMbSAN/shared-swclk-pin-with-boot0-pin-would-i-need-to-connect-nrst-too) at ST forums for details.

Program BOOT_SEL bit to ignore BOOT0 pin altogether. See "2.5 Boot configuration" in datasheet.